# Android - Updating a TextView in a layout included multiple times in main layout

Tags: android, android-layout, mvvm, textview, android-xml

Is there any way to update the text in a textview which is in a included layout and is included lets say 3 times ?

So the scenario is i am calling an API and getting 3 values and using viewModel i am trying to update but it is not getting reflected in the included layout

**1. Main XML**

```
  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/goalAcieved"
                        layout="@layout/item_goals_status"
                        bind:statusname="@{@string/status_achieved}"
                        bind:count="@{viewModel.stateAchievedObsInt}"/>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/goalNotStarted"
                        layout="@layout/item_goals_status"
                        bind:statusname="@{@string/status_not_started}"
                        bind:count="@{viewModel.stateNotStartedObsInt}" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

**2. Include XML**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>

    <variable
        name="count"
        type="androidx.databinding.ObservableInt"/>
</data>

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(count)}"
        android:textAppearance="@style/style_14sp_tab_black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**3. View Model Code Snippet**

```
for (goal in t.goals!!) {
                                    //increments the goal count
                                    if (goal.status!! == 0) {
                                        stateNotStartedObsInt.set(stateNotStartedObsInt.get()+1)
                                    }else if(goal.status!! == 1){
                                        stateAchievedObsInt.set(stateAchievedObsInt.get()+1)
                                    }else if(goal.status!! == 2){
                                        stateNotApplicableObsInt.set(stateNotApplicableObsInt.get()+1)
                                    }
                                }
```

So when i am updating the ObservableInt's, it is not getting reflected in the included xml's textview